# gtk_file_chooser_get_filename, result not freed, memory leak?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk, filechooser

My code:

```
char* fileName;    
fileName=g_filename_from_utf8(gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog)),-1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

The string returned from gtk_file_chooser_get_filename() cannot be referenced, so it can't be freed. Is this a memory leak? Should I assign it to an identifier and then free() it instead of passing it directly to g_filename_from_utf8()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will be a memory leak. You have to free it using g_free() as noted [here](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-get-filename)

Also you have to check for `NULL` as `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename` could return `NULL` on error as well.